# Defining coordinates of a Silverlight image

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to draw a picture in code-behind in Silverlight. Because I will draw so many from them based on a web service information. But for this, when I used image.Margin.Left and top its giving error. How can I handle it?

```
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("wall.png", UriKind.Relative));
        image.Height = 120;
        image.Width = 120;
        image.Margin.Left = 20;

        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Margin property can't be changed by this way, you could do this:

```
image.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer about setting the margin in code is 100% correct.
So this is rather meant as a stimulus to explore the possibilities the framework offers for such a "picture gallery".

Arranging pictures programmatically - You could use a `Canvas`:

```
var image = new Image {
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("wall.png", UriKind.Relative)),
    Height = 120,
    Width = 120
};
Canvas.SetLeft(image, 20);
Canvas.Children.Add(image);
```

As soon as you want pictures to overlap you can easily control which one is on top by setting the z index via `Canvas.SetZIndex(image,42)` (in a `Grid` you would need to rearrange the child order, which is more of a hassle).

Arranging pictures via an `ItemsControl` - out-of-the-box or custom:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WebServiceResult.Images}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate><WrapPanel/></ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=SourceUri}" Height="120" Width="120" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```